# How to create the vector image of crystal structure?

Tags: software-recommendations, crystallography, visualization-software

I am trying to create a vector image of TiO2 crystal because all journals require vector images. When I build the model for calculation, I use `BIOVIA Materials Studio` and `VESTA`, but `BIOVIA Materials Studio`doesn't provide any option to export vector images, and the vector images exported from `VESTA` are blurry.
My question is:
What is the mainstream software for creating a good vector image for crystal structures?

Comment: I don't know what journals you're using, but many journals are happy to have high-resolution PNG. Consider you want at least 200-300 dpi for your image, so a 1200 pixel image is easily large enough for most journal figures (e.g., 2-3" in size).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the resolution of atoms and bonds in VESTA using the properties menu (Ctrl+Shift+P). I recommend doubling the normal numbers and changing the color to black.

[image]